# Rust hdf5 crate: reading a scalar dataset of unknown type

Tags: rust, hdf5

Given an hdf5 [Dataset](https://docs.rs/hdf5/latest/hdf5/dataset/struct.Dataset.html#method.is_scalar), there is the [is_scalar](https://docs.rs/hdf5/latest/hdf5/dataset/struct.Dataset.html#method.is_scalar) method to check if it is a scalar.

However, when I read that scalar, I need to specify the type I wish to read that scalar into as in the code below.

```rust
let ds: Dataset = group.handler
    .dataset(dataset_name.as_ref())
    .unwrap();
if ds.is_scalar() {
    let x: hdf5::types::VarLenUnicode = ds.read_scalar();
}
```

In this example above I specified that I wish to read the scalar into the `hdf5::types::VarLenUnicode` type.

This works fine when I know precisely what type to expect.

In some other circumstances however, I do not have the type information of the hdf5 Dataset in advance.

Depending on the datatype, I wish to process the Dataset differently. Is there a way of checking the datatype of the scalar before reading it?

What would be an idiomatic way of reading an hdf5 Dataset that could contain either a string or a float?

Similarly, is it possible to read and cast the hdf5 dataset into a string even if it contains a float?

Comment: doesn't [`id_type`](https://docs.rs/hdf5/latest/hdf5/dataset/struct.Dataset.html#method.id_type) provide the info you need?

Comment: That always returns `H5I_DATASET` independent of the scalar type.

Comment: You can obtain the `Datatype` from [`.dtype()`](https://docs.rs/hdf5/latest/hdf5/dataset/struct.Dataset.html#method.dtype) and then its `TypeDescriptor` from [`.to_descriptor()`](https://docs.rs/hdf5/latest/hdf5/datatype/struct.Datatype.html#method.to_descriptor).

Comment: Or alternatively, you can use the `Datatype`'s [`.is()`](https://docs.rs/hdf5/latest/hdf5/datatype/struct.Datatype.html#method.is) method to test for particular types.

Comment: Thanks. This raised another question. H5 has many types that can be represented with an `f32` type in Rust. How would you do the mapping from H5 types to Rust scalars?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the library, but the `conv` methods lead me to guess you might be able to simply read into an `f32` and the library will perform the conversion for you?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution that starts with the [to_descriptor()](https://docs.rs/hdf5/latest/hdf5/datatype/struct.Datatype.html#method.to_descriptor) method, eggyal posted on comments.

After getting the `TypeDescriptor` value, we need to handle every possible case (the Rust way).

```rust
match ds_type.to_descriptor().unwrap() {
    hdf5::types::TypeDescriptor::Float(_) => {
        self.show_dataset::<f64>(&ds, dataset, ctx, &mut is_open);
    }
    hdf5::types::TypeDescriptor::VarLenUnicode => {
        self.show_dataset::<hdf5::types::VarLenUnicode>(
            &ds,
            dataset,
            ctx,
            &mut is_open,
        );
    }
    hdf5::types::TypeDescriptor::Integer(_) => {
        self.show_dataset::<i64>(&ds, dataset, ctx, &mut is_open);
    }
    hdf5::types::TypeDescriptor::Unsigned(_) => {
        self.show_dataset::<u64>(&ds, dataset, ctx, &mut is_open);
    }
    hdf5::types::TypeDescriptor::Boolean => {
        self.show_dataset::<bool>(&ds, dataset, ctx, &mut is_open);
    }
    hdf5::types::TypeDescriptor::Enum(_) => todo!(),
    hdf5::types::TypeDescriptor::Compound(_) => todo!(),
    hdf5::types::TypeDescriptor::FixedArray(_, _) => todo!(),
    hdf5::types::TypeDescriptor::FixedAscii(_) => todo!(),
    hdf5::types::TypeDescriptor::FixedUnicode(_) => todo!(),
    hdf5::types::TypeDescriptor::VarLenArray(_) => todo!(),
    hdf5::types::TypeDescriptor::VarLenAscii => {
        self.show_dataset::<hdf5::types::VarLenAscii>(
            &ds,
            dataset,
            ctx,
            &mut is_open,
        );
    }
}
```

Later in the processing, in case of a scalar I just had to display the contents of the scalar types via the `std::fmt::Display`. I used [generic types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics.html) there to avoid code duplication in processing different types.

In the case of a non-scalar (vector), I used `read_raw` to load it.

```rust
fn show_dataset<T: hdf5::H5Type + std::fmt::Display>(
    &mut self,
    ds: &hdf5::Dataset,
    dataset: &str,
    ctx: &egui::Context,
    is_open: &mut bool,
) {
    if ds.is_scalar() {
        let x_data: T = ds.read_scalar().unwrap();
        Window::new(dataset.to_owned())
            .open(is_open)
            .vscroll(true)
            .resizable(true)
            .default_height(300.0)
            .show(ctx, |ui| {
                ui.label(format!("{}", x_data));
            });
    } else {
        let x_data: Vec<T> = ds.read_raw().unwrap();
        let mut table_box = Box::<super::table::TableWindow<T>>::default();
        table_box.set_name(dataset.to_owned());
        table_box.set_data(x_data);
        table_box.show(ctx, is_open);
    }
}
```

There is a caveat in this solution though.

As you probably have already noticed, these types below are not handled. In my application, those types are not needed to be handled but in general I do not know how these types could possibly be handled.

```rust
    hdf5::types::TypeDescriptor::FixedArray(_, _) => todo!(),
    hdf5::types::TypeDescriptor::FixedAscii(_) => todo!(),
    hdf5::types::TypeDescriptor::FixedUnicode(_) => todo!(),
```